# Show that if $X$ is a infinite set, it is connected in the finite complement topology

Tags: general-topology

I know that this question has been answered before, however I have not seen a response that satisfies me on whether my proof will work.

**Proof**

Suppose $A \cup B$ is a separation of $X$. Then WLOG $X-A=B$ and is finite, but this implies that $X-B$ is infinite thus $B$ is not a open set which is a contradiction.

My Question, is it is enough to show that $B$ is not open to get to this contradiction or do I need to go further to reach my contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

This is fine, but you don't need to say 'WLOG'.  If $A\cup B$ is a separation of $X$ then it must be the case that $B$ is finite because $X\setminus A=B$ and $A$ is open, and this doesn't cause any possible generality issues.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you for the edit as well.

Answer (score 0):

A slick way of saying what you've said is that a set is disconnected if it can be partitioned into two non-empty clopen sets. But in this topology no set can be clopen, as a set cannot be both finite and infinite.

Comment: I had a similar proof using that idea, but my wording got out of control so I went with this current proof.

Answer (score 0):

If $A \cup B$ is a disconnection of $X$, this means that $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, disjoint and both open and closed (if one is open, the other is automatically closed as its complement, so we assume both are open or both are closed, usually,and it follows that both sets are clopen).

But by definition the only non-empty closed sets of $X$ are the finite sets, so 
both $A$ and $B$ are finite, which cannot happen, as $X$ is infinite.